# Postgresql rails error: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to query my db to get a set of data, grouped by an attribute `removed_at`; and then from this set of data, get another subset, meeting a criteria `removed_at - activated_at < 7.days` also grouped by `removed_at`.

Since the second set of date is already somewhat included in the first, I'm looking for a way of getting this in a single query.

Below is what I have:

```
beginning_of_month = Date.today.beginning_of_month
all_removals =  removals_during_the_month(beginning_of_month)
removals = all_removals
  .group("date(installations.removed_at)")
  .count

removals_before_7_days = all_removals
  .select{ |removal| removal.removed_at.to_date - removal.activated_at.to_date < 7 }
  .group("date(installations.removed_at)")
  .count


def removals_during_the_month(beginning_of_month)
  Installations
    .where("installations.removed_at > ?", beginning_of_month)
    .uniq
    .select("installations.removed_at, installations.activated_at")
end
```

I am able to get the removals, grouped by the `removed_at` date if I comment out the part where I'm trying to select the removal_before_7_days, but the code breaks when I uncomment that, and do the selection.

The error I get is:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "installations.removed_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT installations.removed_at, installations.acti...
```

I'm kind of stumped here...

How can I go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all I tell you that I'am not ruby-on-rails specialist whatsoever, but looking as PostgreSQL guy:
I think you should put `removed_at - activated_at < 7.days` i `where()` not in `select()`. What you trying to do now is simillar to query like:

```
SELECT removed_at - activated_at < 7.days, count(*)
FROM removals
GROUP BY date(removed_at)
```

It's not proper `GROUP BY` since columns from `SELECT` don't appear in `GROUP BY` clouse. And I belive it acctuallt isn't what you trying to achive anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I finally did was to first get an array of all the data from the database, and then perform the two different operations (`grouping, and selecting the other relevant portion for the other grouping`) on the copy returned from the database as follow:

```
beginning_of_month = Date.today.beginning_of_month
all_removals =  removals_during_the_month(beginning_of_month)
removals_before_7_days = all_removals
          .select{ |removal| removal['removed_at'].to_date - removal['activated_at'].to_date < 7}
          .group_by{ |i| i.removed_at.to_date }
          .map{ |k,v| [k.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), v.count] }
          .to_h

removals = all_removals
                     .group("date(installations.removed_at)")
                     .count

def removals_during_the_month(beginning_of_month)
  Installations
    .where("installations.removed_at > ?", beginning_of_month)
    .uniq
    .select("installations.removed_at, installations.activated_at")
end
```

Basically, the major difference here was the way I was doing my `grouping` for `removals_before_7_days`.

In the previous copy (the one in the question), I was using an `SQL` `.group`, while I'm using a ruby `group_by` now. this made sure that all the actions I was performing on the `all_removals` array are pure array methods in ruby ( `.select`, `.group_by`, `.map`, and `.to_h`)